# Assign a value to a variable through a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am working on a card war game, i tried to assign the number values to the letters on the deck (A-K-Q-J) and other numbers through a dictionary.
but when i run the code sometimes an A loses to other inferior cards or a 10 loses to a 2. Is this the proper way to assign a value to the letters and numbers, or just assign it through a variable (A=14) at the beginning of the program.

```
cardsDict = {"A":14,"K":13,"Q":12,"J":11,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9,"10":10}
from random import shuffle
Deck = []
FaceValues = ["A", "J", "Q", "K"]
def createDeck():
    for i in range(4): 
        for card in range(2,11): 
            Deck.append(str(card))
        for card in FaceValues:
            Deck.append(card)
    shuffle(Deck)
    return Deck
deck = createDeck()
def dealDeck():
    global hand1
    global hand2
    hand1 = Deck[:26]
    hand2 = Deck[26:]
    return hand1, hand2
hands = dealDeck()
def PlayWar(hand1, hand2):
    round = 1
    Player1 = input("Please enter your name: ")
    Player2 = input("Please enter your name: ")
    while len(hand1) > 0 and len(hand2) > 0:      
        Pause = input("Are you ready for the next round? if you are type yes, if you want to see the rules type no: ")
        if Pause == "no":
            print("Rules are:" + "\n" + "1. Deal out deck of 52 cards between two users." + "\n" + "2. Each player plays a card. Higher card wins. Winner takes both cards." "\n" "3. If players tie, then each player puts down three cards, and the third card competes. If a player has less than 3 cards, then they put down all of their cards and their final card competes against the other player's third card. Continue doing this until tie is broken. Winner takes all cards." + "\n" "4. Game is over when a player doesn't have any cards. The player with cards remaining is the winner.")
            
        player1Card = hand1[0]
        player2Card = hand2[0]
        print("round:", round)
        print(player1Card)
        print(player2Card)
        
        if player1Card > player2Card:
            hand1.pop(0)
            hand2.pop(0)
            hand1.append(player1Card)
            hand1.append(player2Card)
            print(Player1 + " wins round " + str(round))
        
        elif player2Card > player1Card:
            hand1.pop(0)
            hand2.pop(0)
            hand2.append(player1Card)
            hand2.append(player2Card)
            print(Player2 + " wins round " + str(round))
        
        elif player2Card == player1Card:
            print("DRAW")
            if len(hand1) < 4:
                hand1 = []
                print(Player1 + " looks you cant match the draw, you lost")
                break
            if len(hand2) < 4:
                hand2 = []
                print(Player2 + " looks you cant match the draw, you lost")
                break
            stash1 = hand1[0:4]
            stash2 = hand2[0:4]
            print(stash1)
            print(stash2)
            if hand1[4] > hand2[4]:
                for card in hand1[0:4]:
                    hand1.remove(card)
                for card in hand2[0:4]:
                    hand2.remove(card)
                for card in stash1 + stash2:
                    hand1.append(card)
                print(Player1 + " wins round: " + str(round))
            elif hand2[4] > hand1[4]:
                for card in hand1[0:4]:
                    hand1.remove(card)
                for card in hand2[0:4]:
                    hand2.remove(card)
                for card in stash1 + stash2:
                    hand2.append(card)
                print(Player2 + " wins round: " + str(round))
            elif hand1[4] == hand2[4]:
                print("SUPERDRAW")
                if len(hand1) < 8:
                    hand1 = []
                    print(Player1 + " looks you can not match the superdraw, you lost!!!")
                    break
                if len(hand2) < 8:
                    hand2 = []
                    print(Player2 + " looks you can not match the superdraw, you lost!!!")
                    break
                stash1 = hand1[0:8]
                stash2 = hand2[0:8]
                print(stash1)
                print(stash2)
                if hand1[8] > hand2[8]:
                    for card in hand1[0:8]:
                        hand1.remove(card)
                    for card in hand2[0:8]:
                        hand2.remove(card)
                    for card in stash1 + stash2:
                        hand1.append(card)
                    print(Player1 + " wins round: " + str(round))
                elif hand2[8] > hand1[8]:
                    for card in hand1[0:8]:
                        hand1.remove(card)
                    for card in hand2[0:8]:
                        hand2.remove(card)
                    for card in stash1 + stash2:
                        hand2.append(card)
                    print(Player2 + " wins round: " + str(round))
       
        if hand1 == []:
            print("Congratulations " + Player2 + " , you won")
        if hand2 == []:
            print("Congratulations " + Player1 + " , you won")               
        round += 1
PlayWar(hand1, hand2)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `deck` variable that you assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't referencing your cardDict when seeing which card is greater.

Inputting the top line of this code fixed the issue when. I tested it out.

```
  if cardsDict[player1Card] > cardsDict[player2Card]:
        hand1.pop(0)
        hand2.pop(0)
        hand1.append(player1Card)
        hand1.append(player2Card)
        print(Player1 + " wins round " + str(round))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cardsDict = {"A": 14, "K": 13, "Q": 12, "J": 11, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9,
             "10": 10}
from random import shuffle

Deck = []
FaceValues = ["A", "J", "Q", "K"]


def createDeck():
    for i in range(4):
        for card in range(2, 11):
            Deck.append(str(card))
        for card in FaceValues:
            Deck.append(card)
    shuffle(Deck)
    return Deck


deck = createDeck()


def dealDeck():
    global hand1
    global hand2
    hand1 = Deck[:26]
    hand2 = Deck[26:]
    return hand1, hand2


hands = dealDeck()


def PlayWar(hand1, hand2):
    round = 1
    Player1 = input("Please enter your name: ")
    Player2 = input("Please enter your name: ")
    while len(hand1) > 0 and len(hand2) > 0:
        Pause = input("Are you ready for the next round? if you are type yes, if you want to see the rules type no: ")
        if Pause == "no":
            print(
                "Rules are:" + "\n" + "1. Deal out deck of 52 cards between two users." + "\n" + "2. Each player plays a card. Higher card wins. Winner takes both cards." "\n" "3. If players tie, then each player puts down three cards, and the third card competes. If a player has less than 3 cards, then they put down all of their cards and their final card competes against the other player's third card. Continue doing this until tie is broken. Winner takes all cards." + "\n" "4. Game is over when a player doesn't have any cards. The player with cards remaining is the winner.")

        player1Card = hand1[0]
        player2Card = hand2[0]
        print("round:", round)

        player1CardVal = cardsDict[player1Card]
        player2CardVal = cardsDict[player2Card]

        print("Player1 Card:" + player1Card + ",Card Value:" + str(player1CardVal))
        print("Player2 Card:" + player2Card + ",Card Value:" + str(player2CardVal))

        if player1CardVal > player2CardVal:
            hand1.pop(0)
            hand2.pop(0)
            hand1.append(player1Card)
            hand1.append(player2Card)
            print(Player1 + " wins round " + str(round))

        elif player2CardVal > player1CardVal:
            hand1.pop(0)
            hand2.pop(0)
            hand2.append(player1Card)
            hand2.append(player2Card)
            print(Player2 + " wins round " + str(round))

        elif player2CardVal == player1CardVal:
            print("DRAW")
            if len(hand1) < 4:
                hand1 = []
                print(Player1 + " looks you cant match the draw, you lost")
                break
            if len(hand2) < 4:
                hand2 = []
                print(Player2 + " looks you cant match the draw, you lost")
                break
            stash1 = hand1[0:4]
            stash2 = hand2[0:4]
            print(stash1)
            print(stash2)
            if hand1[4] > hand2[4]:
                for card in hand1[0:4]:
                    hand1.remove(card)
                for card in hand2[0:4]:
                    hand2.remove(card)
                for card in stash1 + stash2:
                    hand1.append(card)
                print(Player1 + " wins round: " + str(round))
            elif hand2[4] > hand1[4]:
                for card in hand1[0:4]:
                    hand1.remove(card)
                for card in hand2[0:4]:
                    hand2.remove(card)
                for card in stash1 + stash2:
                    hand2.append(card)
                print(Player2 + " wins round: " + str(round))
            elif hand1[4] == hand2[4]:
                print("SUPERDRAW")
                if len(hand1) < 8:
                    hand1 = []
                    print(Player1 + " looks you can not match the superdraw, you lost!!!")
                    break
                if len(hand2) < 8:
                    hand2 = []
                    print(Player2 + " looks you can not match the superdraw, you lost!!!")
                    break
                stash1 = hand1[0:8]
                stash2 = hand2[0:8]
                print(stash1)
                print(stash2)
                if hand1[8] > hand2[8]:
                    for card in hand1[0:8]:
                        hand1.remove(card)
                    for card in hand2[0:8]:
                        hand2.remove(card)
                    for card in stash1 + stash2:
                        hand1.append(card)
                    print(Player1 + " wins round: " + str(round))
                elif hand2[8] > hand1[8]:
                    for card in hand1[0:8]:
                        hand1.remove(card)
                    for card in hand2[0:8]:
                        hand2.remove(card)
                    for card in stash1 + stash2:
                        hand2.append(card)
                    print(Player2 + " wins round: " + str(round))

        if hand1 == []:
            print("Congratulations " + Player2 + " , you won")
        if hand2 == []:
            print("Congratulations " + Player1 + " , you won")
        round += 1


PlayWar(hand1, hand2)
```